# Asp.Net Mvc Route problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have been testing a few options with Route Debugger but no luck. Let me describe what I am trying:

I have all routes "translated" as follows (I needed to translate from English to Portuguese and sometime simplify):

```
routes.MapRoute("Article.Create", "cms/artigo/criar",
                new { controller = "Article", action = "Create" });
```

Everything is working. Since I have all routes defined I think I don't need Default one. So I have something like:

```
// Other translation routes
routes.MapRoute("Article.Create", "cms/artigo/criar",
                new { controller = "Article", action = "Create" });
routes.MapRoute("Article.Edit", "cms/artigo/editar/{id}",
                new { controller = "Article", action = "Edit", id = "" });
routes.MapRoute("Home.Index", "inicio",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Home.Contact", "contacto",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });

// Error Unknown
routes.MapRoute("Error.Unknown", "erro",
                new { controller = "Error", action = "Unknown" });

// Start
routes.MapRoute("Start", "_Default.aspx",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

// Error NotFound
routes.MapRoute("Catch.All", "{*path}",
                new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound", path = "" });
```

If the root goes through the translation mapping with no match then if it is an Unknown Error displays only "http://domain.com/erro"
If not then try to match Home/Index.
Finally goes to catch all route and display only the path as follows "http://domain.com/the/invalid/path

On my Web.Config I have:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Unknown">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

What happens is when I start my site it always goes to NotFound error and not to start page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is would be much easier if you could edit the question and modify the code so its displayed as code. Click the 101010 button and paste the code in there

Comment: why are you not highlight your code using code widget in question

Answer (score 0):

You have defined that the only URL, that points to your home page, is "~/yourapp/_Default.aspx", but your start url is ""~/yourapp/", which will correctly be intercepted by your Catch.All route.
You must change your Start route to this:

```
MapRoute("Start", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Btw.: If you want to unit test your routes, you may be interested in this: [Unit testing ASP.NET MVC routes](https://web.archive.org/web/20171016052706/http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2009/11/02/unit-testing-asp.net-mvc-routes.aspx).
I presents a test fixture to test routes in a tabular style - ideal if you have many possible routes (sample code available).